# Has this system unique solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can i find solutions for this system of equations?

$x\cdot y= a$

$\frac{x}{y}= b$

in which x,y are unknown and a,b known values?

My only hesitation is that the system has many solutions and the equations are linearly dependent. Is this true?How i can elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint regarding unique solution:**

If $(x,y)$ is a solution, what about $(-x,-y)$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** : Your equations being $x\cdot y= a$ and $\frac{x}{y}= b$, the second can be used to eliminate  $x$ since $x = b \cdot y$. Then, replacing in the first equation gives $ b \cdot y^2 = a$. I am sure you can continue with this. Daryl also gave you one track.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach:

Suppose that $a,b>0$, and $x,y$ are presumed to be positive solutions.  Then we can take the $\log$ of both sides to produce the equations
$$
\log x + \log y = \log a\\
\log x - \log y = \log b
$$
Or in other words,
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1} \pmatrix{\log x \\ \log y} = \pmatrix{\log a \\ \log b}
$$
Now, we have a linear algebra problem.

If any of the above assumptions are dropped, however, the solution is no longer necessarily unique.

To add to what the answers have already said: if exactly one of $a$ and $b$ are equal to zero, the system has no solutions.  If both $a$ and $b$ are zero, then any $x,y$ for which $x = 0,y\neq 0$ will be a solution.